# No subscription of azure on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, azure

I am trying to deploy my web app on azure but no available subscription is appearing where I have already subscribed in my azure account .

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. Check the subscriptions available on your Azure account
2. In the Eclipse >Tools>Azure>Sign-in
   You can sign-in with device login or using Service Principal.
3. Here I have signed with device login - After clicking on device login you have to copy the code from Eclipse and paste the code in browser and then the final step is Logging into Azure using username password or Current user if already signed-in.

[image]

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/toolkit-for-eclipse/sign-in-instructions) for more information on signing to Azure account using Eclipse.